# Given a local timezone and a target timezone how can I find the target's current time C#

Tags: c#, timezone-offset

I find many answers that are close but none that match my situation.  We have agents in numerous international time zones answering phones for properties across the US and in some European nations.  I know the properties' time zone as "EST", "PST, etc from a local database of property time zones.  Of course I also know the agents' local times.

What method should I use and what time zone argument should I pass to determine the current time at the property?  Should I pass "EST" if the target property is on the US east coast and what if it is currently Daylight savings time?  Would I then pass "EDT"?  Must I spell out "Eastern Standard Time"?  Is there an ordinal conversion such as 1 for EST...

Comment: Each agents computer has a timezone setting.  When data is stored the local time is automatically store as UTC.  You should be very careful when converting time.  If you need to convert use following :             TimeZoneInfo pacific = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
            DateTime time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, pacific);

Answer (score 1):

I would use [TimeZoneInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)'s static method [ConvertTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx) which Converts a time from one time zone to another.
It receives a dateTime, a sourceTimeZone and a destinationTimeZone.

Regarding the TimeZones, that is something that every OS knows, you can get the list of time zones from TimeZoneInfo, then those objects will know if they observe daylight or not. For that you can use the [FindSystemTimeZoneById](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would use UTC and specify the offset, for example: `2015-12-12T06:53:39-05:00` would indicate that it is currently `01:53:39` on `2015-12-12` in EST.